# after adding sql connector for java still DOES NOT work in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, mysql-connector

You all can see I have added the SQL connector for java but it still gave me the same error anyone can help me:

[image: click this link to picture]

I am using the new version of NetBeans (apache-netbeans IDE 11.3)

Comment: Note that it is probably `jdbc` instead of `jdba` .

Comment: where can i check if it is jdbc or jdba

Comment: Look at the URL from the error message, somewhere you have this URL written with jdba://mysql... , just replace jdba with jdbc .

Comment: ok let me check if it work